# Is there a way to making weighted graph with existed df in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frames which includes the actors and the movies. And my goal is try to find correlation between those. [image]

I have to make adjacency matrices between the actors and movies. I want to make a new dataframe with actors as column names and movies as index names. And put '1' if the actor is playing in this movie and '0' if not. This is the output I'm trying to reach:

[image]

I don't know how to do that, I only saw pandas.crosstab function but did not understand. I'm open to any suggestions. Thank you

Edit: I may not have been able to open the question properly because I was so nervous. I can edit if there is any mistake.

Comment: can you post a sample of the df not the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no duplicates in your data you can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to find existing combinations (and their occurences) and then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) them. Non-existing combinations have to be filled with zeros:

```
df[["Movie_name", "Actor_Name"]].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Comment: There are duplicates.. I mean, some actors plays on multiple movies. I wanted to write '1' for the movies that actor played.

Comment: Hey, this is no problem. With duplicates I mean if there are two (or more) entries where _Wendy Hiller_ is listed for the movie _Pygmalion_ for example. Have you executed the code?